# C# отслеживание изменений в MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, mysqlconnector

Здравствуйте, с недавнего времени знакомлюсь с С# и MySQL и столкнулся с задачей, которая как-то не освещается в интернетах, либо я подослеп и виноват. Но понять не могу.

Используется: VS 2015, Windows Forms + MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Задача: приложение-клиент отслеживает изменения таблице БД на сервере, и если произошли изменения (напр., добавлена запись), то происходит последовательность действий (напр., просто получение и вывод, ну в этом нет проблемы).
Как при работе с MySQL базой реализуется такое отслеживание? К примеру, пока копал, нашел SqlDependency, через который подобное реализуется для MSSQL.

Первое, что приходит на ум - это самому описать поведение, чтобы клиент по таймеру бомбил БД запросом, допустим, предоставления последней записи и сравнивал со своей последней полученной записью (или сравнить TIMESTAMP или id и т.д.). Если идентичны - изменений не было, если отличаются - то загружаем. Но это не выглядит рационально. Это выглядит брутально).

Сейчас читаю про NET Connector на dev.mysql.com, но не могу подобного явно найти. Объясните, пожалуйста, есть ли какое-то стандартное решение?

Comment: *Как при работе с MySQL базой реализуется такое отслеживание?* Штатных средств нет. Так что или рисовать собственное расширение (скажем, UDF, используемая в триггере), или поллинг.

Comment: @Akina хм, печально, видимо все же придется как-то самому придумывать наиболее безболезненное бомбежное решение (не знал, что такой подход называется поллигном, почитал). Спасибо за точный ответ!

Comment: @Akina, почему не как ответ?

Comment: @Андрей Да потому что его ценность с точки зрения получения решения задачи - нулевая.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой вариант:

1) Добавляем триггеры к таблицы, которые при INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE логируют изменения в отдельную таблицу.

```
CREATE TRIGGER articles_log_update AFTER update ON articles 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
INSERT articles_logs (action, row_id, `date`) VALUES ("update", new.id, NOW()); 
END

CREATE TRIGGER articles_log_insert AFTER insert ON articles 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
INSERT articles_logs (action, row_id, `date`) VALUES ("insert", new.id, NOW()); 
END

CREATE TRIGGER articles_log_delete AFTER delete ON articles 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
INSERT articles_logs (action, row_id, `date`) VALUES ("delete", old.id, NOW());
END
```

2) Ставим задачу по крону, чтобы она запускалась каждый час (или день, неделю), дабы проверять таблицу логов
и делать необходимые действия.

Однако сразу хочу сказать, что если это ваша база данных и вы ее проектируете, то не должны допускать, 
чтобы таблица в БД было связующим звеном между частям приложения. Взаимодействие между внутренними и внешними 
сервисами должно быть реализованно в рамках апишек и контрактов.